# Xamarin iOS Callkit and WebRTC with WKWebView (javascript) audio session conflict results in the inability to play local media streams

Tags: xamarin.ios, webrtc, wkwebview, avaudiosession, callkit

Pushkit/Callkit cannot start webrtc webview on iOS, it works well on android. I believe there may have been a conflict between the CallKit audio session and the WebRTC WebView.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. WKWebviewRenderer OnElementChanged

```
webView = new FullWKWebView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(), new WKWebViewConfiguration()
{
AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true,
AllowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true,
AllowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true,
MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true,
MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false,
});
```

2. Pushkit notification

```
CallProviderDelegate.ReportIncomingCall(new NSUuid(call.CallID.ToString()), call.ClientName, call);
```

3. CXProviderDelegate ReportIncomingCall

```
// Create update to describe the incoming call and caller
var update = new CXCallUpdate();
update.RemoteHandle = new CXHandle(CXHandleType.EmailAddress, handle);
update.HasVideo = !call.AudioOnly;
// Report incoming call to system
Provider.ReportNewIncomingCall(uuid, update, (error) =>
{
// Was the call accepted
if (error == null)
{
// Yes, report to call manager
call.CallID = Guid.Parse(uuid.ToString());
CallManager.Calls.Add(new ActiveCall(uuid, handle, false, call));
}
else
{
// Report error to user here
Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", error);
}
});
```

4. CXProviderDelegate DidActivateAudioSession:
   Start WKWebView webrtc (we tried start webview from call answer did not help as well)
   **Expected Behavior**
   Video calling should be fully functional on all platforms with support for both audio and video.

**Actual Behavior** (I believe there may have been a conflict between the CallKit audio session and the WebRTC WebView.)

- android (caller) => android (callee): ok
- ios (caller) => android (callee): ok
- android (caller) => ios (callee): ios video (callee) stopped
- web (caller) => android (callee): ok
- web (caller) => ios (callee): ios video (callee) stopped
- ios (caller) => ios (callee): callee video stopped

**Environment**
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac Preview
Version 17.5 Preview (17.5 build 1766)
Installation UUID: e557854f-a905-44ee-8e30-4046c9714dc5

Runtime
.NET 7.0.1 (64-bit)
Architecture: Arm64
Microsoft.macOS.Sdk 12.3.2372; git-rev-head:754abbf6a3563f6267e5717ae832b4ac25b1f2fb; git-branch:release/7.0.1xx-xcode13.3

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.5.0-3.23056.2+97881342e427ff5cdcba8f12b12ff8e6f3564431

NuGet
Version: 6.4.0.117

.NET SDK (Arm64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.200-preview.22628.1/Sdks
SDK Versions:
7.0.200-preview.22628.1
7.0.100
6.0.405
6.0.403
6.0.401
6.0.400-preview.22330.6
6.0.302
6.0.101
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio(2022).app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK Versions:
6.0.405
6.0.403
6.0.401
6.0.400-preview.22330.6
6.0.106
6.0.101
6.0.408
5.0.404
3.1.426
3.1.425
3.1.423
3.1.421
3.1.416

.NET Runtime (Arm64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
7.0.0
7.0.13
6.0.11
6.0.9
6.0.7
6.0.6
6.0.1

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
6.0.13
6.0.11
6.0.9
6.0.6
6.0.1
5.0.17
5.0.13
3.1.32
3.1.31
3.1.29
3.1.27
3.1.22

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.49
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Xamarin.Android
Version: 13.2.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-5/797e2e1
Android SDK: /Users/vymacmini/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
12.1 (API level 32)
8.0 (API level 26)
12.0 (API level 31)
8.1 (API level 27)
5.0 (API level 21)
11.0 (API level 30)
10.0 (API level 29)
8.1 (API level 25)
9.0 (API level 28)
13.0 (API level 33)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 7.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 34.0.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 33.0.1

Build Information:
Mono: 6dd9def
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop@149d70fe
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite@fdc1e34
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools@9f02d77

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.16.1
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.5.0.33
Hash: f0c0c52
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-5~1
Build date: 2023-02-02 19:20:19 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1245
Hash: 7f8a990
Branch: 7f8a990
Build date: 2023-02-02 19:20:19 UTC

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.5.3.47
Hash: e8b5d371c3
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-5
Build date: 2023-02-02 19:20:14 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode: 14.2 21534
Build: 14C18

Xamarin.Mac
Not Installed

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 16.2.0.2 Visual Studio Community
Hash: 956a059
Branch: xcode14.2
Build date: 2022-12-15 06:15:44-0500

Build Information
Release ID: 1705001766
Git revision: 749808e99f0d0bf8a8eb45fe406840107ffb46b4
Build date: 2023-02-02 19:18:20+00
Build branch: release-17.5
Build lane: release-17.5

Operating System
Mac OS X 13.0.1
Darwin 22.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0
Sun Oct 9 20:14:30 PDT 2022
root:xnu-8792.41.9~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64

**Build Logs**
No build error

Comment: For those who are interested in this issue, please visit the Xamarin team's question here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18078#event-9083264809